# Why does uncertainty of the autocorrelation coefficient increase as lag increases?

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, autocorrelation, statsmodels, partial-correlation

The Python module `statsmodels` contains functions for [ACF](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf.html#statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf) and [PACF](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.pacf.html#statsmodels.tsa.stattools.pacf).   Below is an example from the docs with a plot that shows the (zero-centered) confidence interval on the autocorrelation coefficients.  The ACF doc states that

> 95 % confidence intervals are returned where the standard deviation is computed according to Bartlett’s formula.

I tried to chase down this formula and found some [slides (p.6)](http://www.cmat.edu.uy/%7Emordecki/hk/lecture7.pdf) seeming to state that variance of the estimated autocorrelation approaches $\frac{1+\phi^2}{1-\phi^2}$ as the lag increses, but I don't understand the reasoning behind it.

Is there an intuitive explanation for why the CI widens as lag *k* increases on the ACF plot but not on the PACF?

In my novice understanding, the value of the ACF at k is equivalent to the coefficient you would obtain from univariate regression of the zero-th term as a function of the k-th term.  The value of the PACF at k is like the kth coefficient you would get from a multivariate regression using all terms from 1 to k.  Is that right?

If so, I don't understand why the CI on ACF widens (other than each increase in k diminishes n by one) and why this effect isn't the same for the PACF.

(On the other hand, it looks like in the [R implementation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/106038/39632) the width of the CI of the ACF might be constant-- Does that plot just use the limit of Bartlett's formula for all values of k?)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
dta = sm.datasets.sunspots.load_pandas().data
dta.index = pd.Index(sm.tsa.datetools.dates_from_range('1700', '2008'))
del dta["YEAR"]
sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(dta.values.squeeze(), lags=40)
sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(dta.values.squeeze(), lags=40)
plt.show()
```

[image]